# Sql Server Management Studio 2016 crashes during mouse scrolling

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2016

**Error .NET Runtime ID 1016:**

> Toepassing: Ssms.exe
>   Framework-versie: v4.0.30319
>   Beschrijving: het proces is beëindigd als gevolg van een onverwerkte uitzondering.
>   Uitzonderingsinformatie: System.ArgumentException
>      bij System.Buffer.BlockCopy(System.Array, Int32, System.Array, Int32, Int32)
>      bij Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DataTools.UI.QueryResult.FileStreamReader.ReadArray[[System.Char, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](Int64, Boolean, Int32, Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DataTools.UI.QueryResult.SpecialDataType ByRef, Char[] ByRef, Int32 ByRef)
>      bij Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DataTools.UI.QueryResult.FileStreamReader.ReadString(Int64, Boolean, Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DataTools.UI.QueryResult.SpecialDataType ByRef, System.String ByRef)
>      bij Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DataTools.UI.QueryResult.DiskStorageView.SequentialReadColumn(Int32, Boolean)
>      bij Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DataTools.UI.QueryResult.DiskStorageView.GetCellDataFromFileInternal(Int64, Int32, Boolean)
>      bij Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DataTools.UI.QueryResult.DiskStorageView.GetCellData(Int64, Int32)
>      bij Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DataTools.UI.QueryResult.StorageViewBase.GetCellDataAsStringInternal(Int64, Int32)
>      bij Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DataTools.UI.QueryResult.DiskStorageView.GetCellDataAsString(Int64, Int32)
>      bij Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DataTools.UI.QueryResult.ResultBindingList.GetValue(Int32, Int32)
>      bij Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DataTools.UI.QueryResult.QueryResultControl.DataGridView_CellValueNeeded(System.Object, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellValueEventArgs)
>      bij System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCellValueNeeded(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellValueEventArgs)
>      bij System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCellValueNeeded(Int32, Int32)
>      bij System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.GetValue(Int32)
>      bij System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxCell.GetPreferredSize(System.Drawing.Graphics, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle, Int32, System.Drawing.Size)
>      bij System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.GetPreferredWidth(Int32, Int32)
>      bij System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.OnCellDataAreaMouseEnterInternal(Int32)
>      bij System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.OnMouseMoveInternal(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs)
>      bij System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCellMouseMove(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs)
>      bij System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.UpdateMouseEnteredCell(HitTestInfo, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
>      bij System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnMouseMove(System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
>      bij System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseMove(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
>      bij System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
>      bij System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
>      bij Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DataTools.UI.QueryResult.DTDataGridView.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
>      bij System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
>      bij System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
>      bij System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)

**Error Application Error 1000(100):**

> Naam van toepassing met fout: Ssms.exe, versie: 2015.130.15900.1, tijdstempel: 0x57e2cfaf
>   Naam van module met fout: KERNELBASE.dll, versie: 10.0.10586.589, tijdstempel: 0x57cf9bf1
>   Uitzonderingscode: 0xe0434352
>   Foutmarge: 0x000bdb18
>   Id van proces met fout: 0x4258
>   Starttijd van toepassing met fout: 0x01d22f52c007ec64
>   Pad naar toepassing met fout: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe
>   Pad naar module met fout: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll
>   Rapport-id: cbe6db9b-eb7f-4ddf-8522-288e7e954e72
>   Volledige pakketnaam met fout: 
>   Relatieve toepassings-id van pakket met fout:

Comment: I don't think anyone on StackOverflow could possibly help you with this. You should report this error to the creators of SQL Server Management Studio (ie, Microsoft).

Comment: Perhaps see if there's any SP or new build for SSMS-2016?

Comment: I'm running the latest build from SSMS 2016. Thought mayby someone had a brilliant idea to fix it (maybe a glitchy setting don't know).

The funny thing is the error was also in SSMS 2014 but they fixed it in SP1.